Spring Redis OM repository is not loaded in Spring Boot test context
I have Spring Boot 3.2.0 simple app where I integrated Redis. I'm using redis-om-spring 0.9.0 (this pulls in Jedis client and spring-data-redis). Before I start, demo project is here
I'm using @RedisHash since I'm querying for hash records.
My entity:
@Data
@RedisHash
public class Student{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Indexed
    private String address;

    @Indexed
    private LocalDateTime eventTimestamp;
}

The only config class:
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.example.demo.*"},
        basePackageClasses = {DemoApplication.class})
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableRedisEnhancedRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.*"})
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

The repository:
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Student> {

    List<Student> findByUserNameAndEventTimestampBetweenOrderByEventTimestampAsc(
            String userName, String fromDate, String toDate);
}

Query is issued correctly:
"FT.SEARCH" "com.example.demo.entity.StudentIdx" "@userName:{test} @eventTimestamp:[1728604800000 1713525440080]" "SORTBY" "eventTimestamp" "ASC" "LIMIT" "0" "10000"

Now, with my test configuration I get an error which I don't know how to fix:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.TestClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.StudentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`}

My test class (where I @Autowired repository) is inheriting abstract test class:
@ActiveProfiles({"it"})
@SpringBootTest( //
    classes = {AbstractBaseEnhancedRedisTest.Config.class},//
    properties = { "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true",
            "spring.cloud.config.enabled: false"})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:vss_on.yaml"})
public abstract class AbstractBaseEnhancedRedisTest extends AbstractBaseOMTest {
  @TestConfiguration
  @EnableRedisEnhancedRepositories(basePackageClasses = {SessionRepository.class})
  //@EnableRedisRepositories
  static class Config extends TestConfig {
  }
}

Now, the problem is if I uncomment @EnableRedisRepositories then the test starts, however, it is not studentRepository in test class itself is not of the type com.redis.om.spring.repository.support.SimpleRedisEnhancedRepository, but rather of type org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository which does not how to issue findBy.. methods from Spring Data.
The project I was refering to was Spring Redis OM itself
I tried creating demo Spring Boot app with Redis, but test won't start and if they do start wrong bean is injected.
